# Spring can't load css before login, but after login everything is ok

Tags: spring, spring-security

When I run the app my login page is without images, but when I log in and log out, the login page is styled as it should be.
Can problem be the Security file or something else?

All answers i found are related to the problem where spring won't load CSS at all (.antMatchers(" resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**")) but I don't think this is the same. I couldn't find solution for this.

This is my security file:

```
package com.example.dnevnikjartest.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler) {
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String korisniciQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String ulogeQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(korisniciQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ulogeQuery)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder).dataSource(dataSource);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resource/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/roditelj/**").hasAuthority("roditelj")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin")
                .antMatchers("/ucitelj/**").hasAuthority("ucitelj")
                .antMatchers("/direktor/**").hasAuthority("direktor")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: And why wouldn't it be related? You tell Spring Security to be authenticated for all requests. So if a css is located somewhere else they simply won't load as authentication is required.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. I found the solutions and answer this question. And little edit in my question - css was working fine, images were missing. The problem was I didn't have separate folder for static files inside static. I mixed .css and images together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question.
I insert this code in the class I mentioned in the question and I created folder images in resource -> static. Previously I have all files images files and .css mixed directly in static without folders.

```
 String[] staticResources = {
        "/css/**",
        "/images/**",
        "/fonts/**",
        "/scripts/**",};
```

This is how whole class looks now

```
package com.example.dnevnikjartest.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler) {
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String korisniciQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String ulogeQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(korisniciQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ulogeQuery)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder).dataSource(dataSource);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        String[] staticResources = {
            "/css/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/scripts/**",};

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resource/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/roditelj/**").hasAuthority("roditelj")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin")
                .antMatchers("/ucitelj/**").hasAuthority("ucitelj")
                .antMatchers(staticResources).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }
}
```